# how to check roscore command output after writing the roscore command?

Tags: ros, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

after entering the roscore command,it does not show the prompt, hence not able to type roslist
. what to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250861/how-to-check-roscore-command-output-after-writing-the-roscore-command?/) by [paper](https://answers.ros.org/users/28823/paper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The core keeps running so you

- learn about tmux (or screen) and run it there
- start it as  roscore &
- or simply open a new terminal

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-28**:
Your second suggestion is an option, but will require `pgrep` or similar to be able to stop it again.